# Setup Screen Boundary on iPad Pro 12.9 with SKPhysics

Tags: swift, ipad, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skphysicsworld

I'm trying to create a boundary of physics for the iPad Pro 12.9

This is how I'm doing it:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        let sceneBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
        sceneBody.friction = 0
        self.physicsBody = sceneBody

....
}
```

But the Y is way off in Landscape (much lower and higher than the actual screen), and a little ways off in Portrait. But the X is right in both.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

### Update

I've added a print to the above, and its showing the maxX and maxY of self.frame to be 375 and 667 respectively. In landscape mode. Neither of those numbers are what they should be, as far as I can tell, yet the X value works correctly whilst Y is way off the top and bottom of the screen.

This iPad model's screen resolution is 2732x2048 (half that in points) so I don't see a correlation between these numbers and the reported frame size.

Comment: Why wouldn't they be those numbers?  That is the size of your scene when you set it up

Comment: looks to me like you built your scene to be iPhone 6 size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has something to do with the way you're scaling the scene. When presenting a scene, you may be setting the [`scaleMode`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skscene/1519562-scalemode) property of the scene, which is of type [`SKSceneScaleMode`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skscenescalemode). There are four different modes:

- `fill`: Each axis is scaled independently in order to fit the whole screen
- `aspectFill`: The scene is scaled to fill the screen, but keeping the aspect ratio fixed. This is the one your scene is probably set to.
- `aspectFit`: The scene is scaled to fit inside the screen, but keeps the aspect ratio. If the scene has a different aspect ratio from the device screen, there will be letter boxing.
- `resizeFill`: The scene is resized to fit the view.

Comment: I'm not setting this, so far as I know. Working from default SpriteKit game template.

Comment: From the default template, this is being set in `GameViewController.swift` in the `didMoveToView()` function.

Comment: you would be using .aspectFill then

Comment: You can edit the original size of the scene by going to `GameScene.sks`, selecting Scene, and in the attributes inspector, select the `size` pop-up menu and choose iPad Pro 12.9"

Comment: Does this mean there isn't a truly generic "size" that's utterly adaptable? That it's always hard set somewhere?

Comment: and why does an x value of 375 work correctly on the iPad Pro, despite having no correlation to the actual width of the screen? It works correctly in both landscape and portrait positions, despite being wrong in both.

Comment: The actual resolution of the device and the size of the scene have nothing to do with each other. SpriteKit uses a different unit than device screen pixels.

Comment: So how do I get the size of the view? eg. I want to put something in the middle of the screen, regardless of the device size. Or I want to build a wall around the screen, like the above question.

Comment: This question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221424/swift-spritekit-get-visible-frame-size